# SSIS - Exporting multiple files from one sql table.

Tags: sql, ssis, text-files

I have about 30 files that will need to be exported from one sql table. What I have now is creating a sql table for each file, then exporting the contents of that individual table. This works fine but I really didn't want to have 30 tables on the server. Is there a way to export from one table using 30 different sql queries?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to do this in SSIS, you can just use a SQL Data Reader Source object for each query, and pipe the results to a Flat File destination object. No need to create a table to store the results of your query.

Comment: I am using visual studio 2008 and don't see a sql data reader source object in the toolbox. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Thanks @N West for the suggestion, it isn't called sql data reader in 2008, it is ADO.NET data source. I chose Data access mode of 'sql command' and entered my sql code into the box, then created a txt file destination and after I add 29 more, I will be done...

Comment: If your files are all the same column format, you could do this using a loop and change the file name & parameter for the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on your data need and how complicated the export is but... generally people do not create an export table per export.  Data Transform Task's source can be a table (which you are currently using) or a stored procedure or a view.

I would need to know more about your structure to advise more accurately but... one table per export is definitely not the best solution.

I would use a parameterized stored procedure if possible.

Comment: Below is one query, they all will look like this except for different payors...when you say parameterized sp, how would I apply this example to that? 
SELECT  columns         
  FROM [Auto_276_ToBeProcessed] a
  left  join Auto_276_Payor_receiver_lookup b on 'CAIDNY' = b.[PAYOR_MNEM]
  where [Inv current fsc num] = '105'